# Can you play Clash of Clans using the same Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, game-center, clash-of-clans

Me and my brother want to play Clash of Clans with different game progress but somehow he always gets my progress when he plays it.

He got a new Apple ID and a new Game Center, but somehow the same problem is happening: we can't play the game separately - we tried and tried but it still doesn't work.

What can we do to play the game using different progress?

Answer (score 1):

This game saves progress to Game Center. If you both use the same AppleID for Game Center to log in, that would explain what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but village is on your game center acc, so you must change your game center account and the game will start from zero.