# Two Clash of Clan accounts under one Game Center account

Tags: ios, apple-id, game-center, clash-of-clans

I have a problem that I am worried about with my Clash of Clans game. I originally started playing the game on my iPad. I was not able to play it while I was out because my iPad did not have an internet connection. So I downloaded the game on my iPhone 5 so I could play it everywhere and started a new base. At the time, I did not know that they were on the same Game Center account. Now every time I get onto my phone, it asks if I would like to load my TH 7 village, but my progress on this base will be lost. Well my base on my iPhone is a lot higher then the one on my iPad now. If I have to lose one account, I am OK with losing the one on my iPad lvl 47 rather than my lvl 70 on my iPhone. Can someone explain to me what I need to do to save my lvl 70 account?

I am OK right now but when i get a new phone I will lose it because it is not linked to a Game Center account anymore. How can I ditch the level 47 village and keep the level 70 village?

Long story short: I have Clash of Clans on my iPhone and on my iPad. Both have different villages. Started my village on the iPad first. Both are under the same Game Center account. Everytime I get onto my phone it ask if i want to load my TH 7 King Tom village. I always say no because it is not high lvl like on my phone. Is there a way to keep both villages and put one under a different game center or can I delete the low level one and just leave the high level one? Just dont want to lose my lvl 70 village is all because I have put so much money into it.

Thanks

Comment: Does reading this answer help you figure out a plan? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88135/can-you-play-clash-of-clans-using-the-same-apple-id

Comment: I did not really understand what was said on that link because there were 2 different answers really. and i am ok with deleting my low account if i have to. just need to know how to and make my big account my main one.

Comment: Why not edit your post for grammar and then explain what you want? I bet someone will have ideas if the question is clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load clash of clans village asking me to update - state of village](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124380/load-clash-of-clans-village-asking-me-to-update-state-of-village)

Answer (score 1):

How open are you to creating a new Game Center account?

If yes, then follow the steps below:

Steps are taken from http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4314?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

1. Open the Game Center app
2. Tap on your email/username and click sign out
3. Tap on the Create a new account button
4. Follow the steps on the screen
5. Sign in to your new GC account and open Clash of Clans
6. Congrats! Your village should be linked to the new GC account. To test it out, sign in to another device with Clash of Clans and tap on OK/Confirm

If no, well..... * shrug *. IDK what to do.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I have gotten the same problem but in the opposite way. I am not sure but I think you need to ( on which ever device you aren't using and dont want the base) log out or delete clash of clans from Game Center account. It is hard but you can look it up. Easier will be just deleting the game on iPad or phone (which ever you don't want to keep), so that the message will stop appearing. BUT THE EASIEST is to just always click on Cancel when the note about replacement appears (This is what I do). Hope I helped. Good luck!

Comment: Deleting the app on the other device or signing out on the other device doesn't work. The Supercell server still has the lower level village linked to the GC account, so it will continue to ask you.