# Load clash of clans village asking me to update - state of village

Tags: game-center, clash-of-clans

Recently clash of clans updated. When I logged into a another game centre account it asked me "Do you want to replace it? if yes type confirm."

Will I lose my other village if I type confirm ?

Answer (score 1):

No. I do that all the time. I have a TH 3 village and a TH 8 village. When switching from my TH 8 to TH 3, it gives me the message. I later switch back to my TH 8 and it is perfectly fine. From here (http://www.reddit.com/r/ClashOfClans/comments/1n51uh/is_it_possible_to_have_2_villages_on_one_device/) it says (quoted from Chief LPFX):

> Each time you switch you will get a Game Center Alert asking you if you want to discard this village and load the other one. You may need to type "CONFIRM" to continue. Don't worry, the other village is not deleted.

So, you can switch between them. The CONFIRM message is just to make sure you didn't mean to accidentally switch.